# How to apply Chebyshev's inequality to this problem?

Tags: probability

One more task that I freely admit comes from a former test:

Consider a graph consisting of $n$ triangles conjoined with their sides, for example for $n=5$ and $n=6$:

[image]

We color each vertex randomly and independently on one of $2$ colors. Let $X$ denote the number of triangles that have each vertex in the same color.

A) Compute $\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)$

B) Compute $\operatorname{Var}\left(X\right)$

C) Estimate from above $\operatorname{P}\left(X\geq \frac n2\right)$

## My solution attempt:

**A)** $X=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$ where $X_i=1$ iff $i$th triangle has all vertices in the same color and $X_i=0$ otherwise

For each color there is $\frac1{2^3}=\frac18$ probability it has all vertices in each of the two colors, which gives us $\frac14$ probability all vertices are in the same color. Thus for any $i$ we have $\operatorname{E}\left(X_i\right)=\frac14$ and from the linearity of expected value we have $\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{E}\left(X_i\right)=\frac n4$

**B)** First let's compute $\operatorname{E}\left(X^2\right)$:

$\operatorname{E}\left(X^2\right)=\operatorname{E}\left(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i\right)^2=\operatorname{E}\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n X_iX_j\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\operatorname{E}\left(X_iX_j\right)$

Now let's split it to four cases:

**Case 1**: $i=j$ Then trivially $\operatorname{E}\left(X_iX_j\right)=\frac14$ since obviously $X_i^2$ is always equal $X_i$. Of course this case appears $n$ times in the above sum.

**Case 2**: $\left|i-j\right|=1$ Then $X_iX_j=1$ iff four vertices are in the same color, thus $\operatorname{E}\left(X_iX_j\right)=\operatorname{P} \left(X_iX_j\right)=\frac18$ This case appears $2\left(n-1\right)$ times in the above sum (there are $n-1$ possibilities that $i=j-1$ and $n-1$ possibilities that $i-1=j$)

**Case 3**: $\left|i-j\right|=2$ Then $X_iX_j=2$ iff five vertices are in the same color, thus  $\operatorname{E}\left(X_iX_j\right)=\operatorname{P} \left(X_iX_j\right)=\frac1{16}$ This case appears $2\left(n-2\right)$ times in the above sum (there are $n-2$ possibilities that $i=j-2$ and $n-2$ possibilities that $i-2=j$)

**Case 4**: $\left|i-j\right|\geq3$ In this case $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent so $\operatorname{E}\left(X_iX_j\right)=\operatorname{E}\left(X_i\right)\cdot\operatorname{E}\left(X_j\right)=\frac1{16}$ Now this case can be split into a number of sub-cases split by value of $\left|i-j\right|=k$, for $3\leq k\leq n-1$. Each sub-case occurs $2\left(n-k\right)$ times, so in the end the whole Case 4 occurs $2\sum^{n-3}_{l=1}l=\left(n-3\right)\left(n-2\right)$ times.

In the end $\operatorname{E}\left(X^2\right)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\operatorname{E}\left(X_iX_j\right)=\frac n4+\frac{2\left(n-1\right)}8+\frac{2\left(n-2\right)}{16}+\frac{\left(n-3\right)\left(n-2\right)}{16}=\frac{4n}{16}+\frac{4n-4}{16}+\frac{2n-4}{16}+\frac{n^2-5n+6}{16}=\frac{n^2+13n+2}{16}$

Thus $\operatorname{Var}\left(X\right)=\operatorname{E}\left(X^2\right)-\left(\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)\right)^2=\frac{n^2+13n+2}{16}-\frac{n^2}{16}=\frac{13n+2}{16}$

**C)** Here be dragons, I guess.

I can easily employ Markov's inequality. Since Markov's inequality can be equivalently stated this way: $\operatorname{P}\left(X\geq c\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)\right)\leq\frac1c$ for any $c>0$, then for $c=2$ we have $\operatorname{P}\left(X\geq \frac n2\right)\leq\frac12$.

However, since we were told to compute the variance beforehand, I'm guessing that is is probably required that we compute a better estimate with Chebyshev's inequality.

I'm not sure how to employ Chebyshev here. I can try:

Chebyshev's inequality can be equivalently stated like that: $\operatorname{P}\left(\left|X-\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)\right|\geq c\operatorname{SD}\left(X\right)\right)\leq\frac1{c^2}$ for any $c>0$

Now let's transform this inequality inside the $\operatorname{P}$ operator:

$\left|X-\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)\right|\geq c\cdot \operatorname{SD}\left(X\right)\iff\left(X-\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)\right)^2\geq c^2\operatorname{Var}\left(X\right)\iff\left(X-\frac n4\right)^2\geq c^2\frac{13n+2}{16}\iff X^2+\frac{n^2}{16}-\frac n2X\geq\frac{13n}{16}c^2+\frac18c^2$

Wow. The outcome is *vicious*. Whatever value the constant $c$ would be, I can never make this inequality equivalent to $X\geq \frac n2$.

Well, I could say that $\operatorname{P}\left(X\geq \frac n2\right) = \operatorname{P}\left(X^2\geq\frac{n^2}4\right)\leq\operatorname{P}\left(X^2+A\geq\frac{n^2}{4}-B\right)$ for positive $A$ and $B$; however I can't do this because of this $\frac{n}2X$ part.

How to proceed from now on?